# Calculating percentage with comparing two string fields

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator

i have data like below

[image]

i need output like below

[image]

Comment: You have tags for ArcGIS Desktop and the Field Calculator but make no mention of having used either in your question body.  As a relatively new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  As it stands I think your question would benefit from being heavily revised to try and make what you are asking clearer.  I recommend reviewing http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/a/3353/115 for tips on how to structure a good question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use field calculator and some similarity comparison. How do you calculate similarity in your example?

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

def similar(a, b):
    return SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()*100

similar( !name1!, !name2!)
```

[image]

Comment: it's working but above percentage query working based on individual letter. sometimes it may give wrong percentage like
EX: net and ten it give 100% 

so is there any possibility to give based on words.